# Insertions of same row is happening and how to reject an insertion if iti is already present in DB Django-rest-framework,PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a backend for social app. While inserting friend relation in database, It is also inserting relations already present in DB.

Example:
User 1 and User 2 are already friends
So,The row in DB: 1,2,3,date
Now the DB shouldn't accept the same row anymore but it is accepting !!!
How to reject or restrict multiple insertions of same rows.

My View:

```
class Friendship(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating Friendship"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = UserFriendSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.FriendCreate,IsAuthenticated)
    queryset = Friends.objects.all()


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Sets the friendship status to user"""

        serializer.save(username = self.request.user)
```

My serializer:

```
class UserFriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for adding and removing Friends"""

    class Meta:
        model = Friends
        fields = ('user_id_1','user_id_2','status',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create user friendship with lesser id in first column"""

        friend_1 = validated_data['user_id_1']
        friend_2 = validated_data['user_id_2']

        if friend_1.pk > friend_2.pk:
            temp = friend_1
            friend_1 = friend_2
            friend_2 = temp

        friend = Friends(
            user_id_1 = friend_1,
            user_id_2 = friend_2,
            status = validated_data['status'],
        )

        friend.save()

        return friend
```

My Model:

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    '''Friend's or Relationship between user's and their relation status'''
    user_id_1 = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_a')
    user_id_2 = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_b')
    status    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    friends_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns model as a String"""
        return str(self.user_id_1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Friends"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correct, you need the [unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    """Friend's or Relationship between user's and their relation status"""
    user_id_1 = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_a')
    user_id_2 = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_b')
    status    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    friends_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns model as a String"""
        return str(self.user_id_1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Friends"
        unique_together = ("user_id_1", "user_id_2")
```

Comment: @DilipKrishna glad to help you!